# React Native : creating both props and state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

A noob question.

I am having this component to contain both props and state.

Can someone tell me how i can define props for a class based component ?

I am getting the following error

```
"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: logstringdate"
```

This is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';



export default class Logitem extends Component {

  constructor(props)  {
    super(props);
    const { logstringdate, bmi, weight, logdate } = props;
  }


onWeightClick = () => {
  console.log('The element ==> '+logdate);
}


render() {

  return (
    <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
              <View style={styles.headerContentStyle}>
                    <Text>{logstringdate}</Text>
                    <Text>{bmi}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.thumbnailContainerStyle}>
                    <Text onPress={this.onWeightClick}>{weight}</Text>
              </View>
    </View>
  );

}
};

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2},
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop:10,
  },
  thumbnailContainerStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row'

  },
  headerContentStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-around'
  },
};
```

I would like to have logstringdate, bmi, weight, logdate as props.

Can someone tell me what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when inside a `class` methods you should reference properties with the `this` key word:

```
const { logstringdate, bmi, weight, logdate } = this.props;
```

Also, You declared the variables inside the `constructor` block scope (which you are not really using them) but in your `render` method which is a separate block context you didn't declare the variable:

```
const { logstringdate } = this.props;
```

Or:

```
<Text>{this.props.logstringdate}</Text>
```